# Hive query failing with analysis exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

```
hc.sql("select SpecialityId, IsAvailable from Provider_Speciality where ProviderId in ('330003','330004','333301') and SpecialityId = 'Splty101';");
```

The above query is failing with org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near ''Splty101'' ';' '' in expression specification; line 1 pos 3195. 
I am using Hive on Spark-scala here.

However, it is running fine when I run it from hive CLI, there is no issue at all.

Can anyone please help me finding the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the semi-colon (`;`) from the end of the query